# Haskell Recursive List Summation

Tags: list, haskell, recursion

I'm new to functional programming and haskell, so I'm just starting out learning both by attempting some Euler problems. This involves a great deal of list summations.

So I'm trying to write a recursive list summation function that takes one list as input and returns an integer as output, for instance:

```
-- Sum up a list
listsum :: [int] -> int
listsum [a:b:[]] = a + b
listsum x = head x + listsum tail x
```

When compiling this code, I receive this error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[[int] -> int]'
            with actual type `[a0] -> [a0]'
Relevant bindings include
  x :: [int]
    (bound at C:\Users\Rade\Documents\GitHub\haskell\euler_2.hs:15:9)
  listsum :: [int] -> int
    (bound at C:\Users\Rade\Documents\GitHub\haskell\euler_2.hs:14:1)
Probable cause: `tail' is applied to too few arguments
In the first argument of `listsum', namely `tail'
In the second argument of `(+)', namely `listsum tail x'
```

I've tried to research the pattern matching, but I cannot understand what it means with expected type versus actual type. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
listsum [a:b:[]] = a + b
```

Here, `a:b:[]` means the list `[a, b]`, so `[a:b:[]]` means `[[a, b]]`, which is not what you want.

Simply change this to

```
listsum (a:b:[]) = a + b
```

Now, in

```
listsum x = head x + listsum tail x
```

the part `listsum tail x` means *apply `listsum` to `tail`, and then apply the result to `x`*. I suppose you meant *apply `tail` to `x` and then apply `listsum` to the result*, which can be expressed as `listsum (tail x)`.

---

I suggest a bit cleaner implementation, which assumes that summing empty list yields zero.

```
listsum [] = 0
listsum (x:t) = x + listsum t
```

This differs in functionality from your implementation, since it handles lists with zero or one element correctly.

Comment: You were right about the [a:b:[]] issue, but I still receive the same error. 

Furthermore, your cleaner implementation compiles, but is it the same thing? Wouldn't 1 be interpreted as the value 1 and not some list of some size?

Comment: @Rade I found another problem with your implementation; I'll update the answer soon.

Comment: @Rade by the way, it is not "1", it is small letter "L". I changed it to prevent further confusion.

Comment: Oops, my mistake there! I run into this issue when using it tho:  `No instance for (Num int) arising from the literal '0'`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? I'm trying to simpy say `sum = listsum [1..10]`

Comment: @Rade Oh, I didn't notice that, sorry. In Haskell, type names begin with capital latters, while `int` is treated as a *type variable*; it's name really has almost no meaning. When we use `(+)` operator on objects of variable type `int`, Haskell expects `int` to be an instance of class `Num`, where `(+)` is defined, but `int` has no constraints in the function signature. You can simply change `int` to `Int`, where the latter is the standard Haskell integer type. Alternatively, you can change the signature to `listsum :: (Num a) => [a] -> a` and learn about polymorphic functions and typeclasses.

Comment: Thank you so very much, this is exactly the explanation I needed to understand. Thank you very much for all of your help!

Comment: @Rade I'm happy to be of service.